# Return paths of a file based on its directory/ sub directories of root

Tags: python, file, os.walk

I have few paths which has files files with same names . The paths of files are created in the form of timeseries. I want to perform operations on files which fall in same month.How to fetch files A.txt from only first 10 days of a month at a time(using the directory name)?

```
Path directories:
/users/rapabba/20210602T010225/**/A.txt
/users/rapabba/20210602T090225/**/A.txt
/users/rapabba/20210606T130225/**/A.txt
/users/rapabba/20210622T031225/**/A.txt
.
.
.
/users/rapabba/20211222T031225/**/A.txt
```

Comment: split the path string with different delimiters,  with "/" to get the time, with "T" to get the date and then use indexing to get the month. show some effort and if you got stuck people will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can use placeholders:

```
from pathlib import Path

basepath = Path("/users/rapabba")
year = 2021
month = 6
for filename in basepath.glob(f"{year:04d}{month:02d}*/**/A.txt"):
    print(filename)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. How about working with files that are created in the first 10 days or 15 days?